# What is going on with my Visual Studio Code?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, codespaces

After I had problems with saving my code and it having two different saves, I deleted it and now I can't load up any of my code and the terminal doesn't give me any prompts and most of the time it just says that it can't reconnect.

Also I tried deleting my codespace and making a new one but it brought back my code from the previous one and still has the same problems.

And before I deleted my codespace it gave me this error:

> VSCodeWorkbench mount failed with "Failed to connect to relay url Code: 1006 Reason: "

Example:

[image: example]

Example 2:

[image: example 2]